# How to create a responsive table of square cells using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create an 8*8 table using HTML and CSS, where the first column and row both serve as headers (preferably with the height of the header row equal to the width of the header column), and with all of the table body cells being square.

Here is my current HTML and CSS:

```html
<table id="grid-main" class="grid" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>
            <th scope="col">C</th>
            <th scope="col">D</th>
            <th scope="col">E</th>
            <th scope="col">F</th>
            <th scope="col">G</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">4</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">5</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">6</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">7</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
td {
    padding: 0%;
    height: 12.5%;
    width: 12.5%;
    border-style: solid;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

#grid-main {
    padding: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

However, the cells in the table generated using the above code are neither square, nor all the same size (the table is within a div occupying about 50% of the page).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

This is what I'm looking to create
[image: Table]

EDIT 2:

I accidentally added 1 extra row and column to that diagram, but other than that it's correct

Comment: Assuming your data is genuinely tabular, ie grid would not be semantically correct, stick to table but why set both width and height of the table if you know you want to set aspect ratio. Set just one of width or height and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use divs in a simple grid. This code "margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;" solves the border duplications.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .table-grid {
                display:grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
                text-align:center;
            }
            .table-grid-cell {
                border:1px solid grey;
                margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;
                padding:5px;
            }
            .table-header-cell {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width:540px) {
                .table-grid-cell {
                    padding:0px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table-grid">
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell table-header-cell">Header</div>
    
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
    
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
    
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
            <div class="table-grid-cell">Data</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```